# How can I avoid too much recursion error when trying to extend a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a class in javascript with a property that is a function.  When I try to redefine that function like this:

```
myObject.someBehavior = function()
{
  myObject.someBehavior();
  extraLogic();
};
```

I am getting a "Too much recursion error".  I understand why I am getting this error, the myObject.someBehavior is holding a reference to the function, so changing the function does not change the reference.  So my question is how can I avoid this?

To clarify, I am trying to extend a behavior function of a javascript object.  IN C#, I would just override the method, calling the base class's version first.  Not sure how to do this in javascript.

Comment: Why you need to call the function recursively? Is there any condition that'll exit from the recursive function?

Comment: You don't seem to have a base case in your recursive call. You need to have some condition that will *end* the recursion process or it will just loop forever.

Comment: I am trying to avoid recursion, this is my problem. I Just want to make a new function as an extension of the old one (some extra code after the existing code)

Comment: Does the new function need the same name?

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this with [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). I'm not sure whether it's a good idea for what you're trying to do though. You might be better off learning [how inheritance works in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

```
myObject.someBehavior = (function(oldFunction) {
    return function() {
        oldFunction();
        extraLogic();
    };
})(myObject.someBehavior);
```